# Quickest way to create multiple copies of the same file with slightly different file names

Tags: vba, excel, filesystems

I'm currently doing the following:

```
Global myNames() As Variant

Sub createEmptyTemplates(ByVal destPath As String, ByVal tempPath As String)

':: this is just to create a load of copies of a template

Dim aName
For Each aName In myNames()

    Dim myDest As String
    myDest = destPath & "\" & "Copy of template named - " & aName & ".xlsx"

    FileSystem.FileCopy tempPath, myDest

Next aName 

End Sub
```

Before this sub-routine is called the variant array `myNames()` is filled with 200 variant/strings. The template that it is using is quite a complex excel file.

After creating all the files it than proceeds to a further routine that opens each file importing relevant data.

The above routine is not so quick - maybe 5mins in total. Is there a more efficient way of creating all these file copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and have reasonably surprising results that show that using a `filesystemObject` is way better than the other two approaches I tested.

The template is approx 2000KB. I have limited the run to just 4 copies of the template.

Version1 FileSystem.FileCopy: Times to create each copy:

- 2.737s
- 2.722s
- 2.406s
- 2.496s

Code:

```
Global myNames() As Variant

Sub createEmptyTemplates(ByVal destPath As String, ByVal templateFullPathName As String)

':: this is just to create a load of copies of a template

Dim aName
For Each aName In myNames()

    Dim myDest As String
    myDest = destPath & "\" & "Copy of template named - " & aName & ".xlsx"

    FileSystem.FileCopy tempPath, myDest

Next aName 

End Sub
```

Version2 Scripting.FileSystemObject.CopyFile (with early binding Ref): Times to create each copy:

- 0.244s
- 0.084s
- 0.093s
- 0.080s

Code:

```
 Global myNames() As Variant

    Sub createEmptyTemplates(ByVal destPath As String, ByVal templateFullPathName As String)

    ':: this is just to create a load of copies of a template

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim aName
    For Each aName In myNames()

        Dim myDest As String
        myDest = destPath & "\" & "Copy of template named - " & aName & ".xlsx"

        fso.CopyFile _
           Source:=templateFullPathName, _
           Destination:=myDest

    Next aName 

    If Not (fso Is Nothing) Then Set fso = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Version3 wbObjVar.SaveCopyAs: Times to create each copy:

- 3.348s
- 3.740s
- 3.179s
- 3.418s

Code:

```
Global myNames() As Variant

Sub createEmptyTemplates(ByVal destPath As String, ByVal templateFullPathName As String)

':: this is just to create a load of copies of a template

Dim t As Excel.Workbook
Set t = Excel.Workbooks.Open(templateFullPathName, , False, , , , True)

Dim aName
For Each aName In myNames()
    t.SaveCopyAs  destPath & "\" & "Copy of template named - " & aName & ".xlsx"
Next aName 

If Not (fso Is Nothing) Then Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider ?

```
Sub M_snb()
  sn=array("name1", "name2",....,"")

  for each it in sn
   thisworkbook.savecopyas "G:\OF\" & it & ".xlsx"
  next
End Sub
```

Comment: hello snb. The template is not `thisworkbook`. In `vba` my templates are generally `xlsx` files whereas the `vba` is in a controlling `xlsm` file. You think I'd be quicker to 1. Open template 2. Make that template an object variable 3. Use excel-vba method `savecopyas` ? I'll test and get back to you. My initial feeling is that my original code should be a little faster as no files are actually opened?

Comment: You can use the macro in another workbook or in the personal.xlsb. In that case you'll have to replace 'thisworkbook' by 'activeworkbook'.