# VBA code that executes two .bat files one after another

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, wscript.shell

I'm trying to write a code that would create and execute two batch scripts, one after another. The 1st makes a given number of copies of my pdf file (makecopies.bat) and the 2nd one changes the names of the copies according to a list of names. Thus, it is crucial that the execution of the 1st goes to completion before the 2nd one runs. That is why I refrain from using `Call Shell("cmd.exe /k cd " & CurDir & " && makecopies.bat", vbHide)` - I tried it and it would result in overlapping execution of scripts.

Instead, I tried to make it work with WScript.Shell, because that method allows setting `waitOnReturn` value. However, the problem is as follows (I need to execute two scripts, I use one as an example):

- the part below  works fine on my own laptop and when I try to run the code on my company computer (the one I intend to use the code at), it gives "Run time error -2147024894(80070002) Automation error The file cannot be found"

```
 Dim wsh As WshShell
 Set wsh = New WshShell
 Dim makecopies As String
 Dim script_makecopies As Long
                
 Open CurDir & "\makecopies.bat" For Output As #FileNumber
 Print #FileNumber, Range("B2").Value
 Close #FileNumber
                
 makecopies = CurDir & "\makecopies.bat"

 script_makecopies = wsh.Run(makecopies, windowStyle:=0, waitOnReturn:=True)
```

- I tried to change my code in order to overcome the problem - and it kind of worked, creating another problem in turn :D I replaced the last line with `wsh.Run "cmd.exe /k makecopies", 0, True`. This gets the job done, however at this point Excel stops responding and the rest of code (i.e. the second batch file) is not executed. I noticed that when removing `/k` Excel works fine and the code that follows this line is executed, but the batch (makecopies.bat) itself is not.

Does anyone have any idea how can I make it work? (Thank you in advance!)

Comment: Any reason that you don't do it directly in Excel? You can copy and rename files with VBA. Writing and execute an Script is error prone and often blocked by policy.

Comment: Thank you, making copies with VBA could come in useful there (however the number of copies is a variant) - I need to try it out. Though I'm not sure it would work with renaming the files - the names are not sequential. Sure I will try - I'm new to VBA and my current script is thought as an automation of an Excel sheet that generates two 'scripts' I would then copy + paste to cmd. Maybe I just need to change my thinking.

Comment: I ended up with an array-based solution, using `filesystemObject` method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268391/quickest-way-to-create-multiple-copies-of-the-same-file-with-slightly-different helped a lot.